# Expectation Value Involving $s$-Wave Solutions to Central Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

I previously posted a question regarding the expectation value described below, but it was closed because the question was not developed enough. Since I was given the option to delete it, I deleted it; however, now I think I have developed some additional ideas and observations and therefore I am posting this related question.

Consider a central potential $V(r)$. When I computed the following expectation value for an $s$-wave solution to the Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom, i.e. a solution of the form $\psi = \phi(r) Y_{00} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}} \phi(r)$, I noticed the following:

$$
\langle \psi | \frac{dV}{dr} |\psi \rangle \propto |\phi(0)|^2
$$

Basically, I plugged in several hydrogen radial functions $R_{n,\ell}(r)$ found in Griffiths Quantum Mechanics and noticed this behavior.

Is the behavior true for any central potential $V(r)$? If so what would be the proportionality constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be true for the harmonic oscillator, if you plug in the $n$-th  solution there, your $\phi(0)$ becomes lower ($\sim 1/\sqrt{n}$ if it is in one dimension, steeper when in more dimensions). At the same time the $dV/dr$ expectation value becomes actually *larger* because the radial wave function will see more of the larger $r$ region, where $dV/dr$ is larger.

Of course the harmonic oscillator in in this respect opposite to the Coulomb potential, which has its $dV/dr$ decreasing with larger $r$. For that situation what you describe can be true, but certainly not on general.

Comment: Thank you very much